# jquery longclick on <option> element

Tags: jquery, html, events, long-click

i am trying to trigger an event on an option from a dropdown menu.
for example:

```
<select id="select1">
<option id="1">1</option>
<option id="2">1</option>
</select>
```

i used an example on http://api.jquerymobile.com/taphold/ and appended the event to the 
option with id=1:

```
$( "#1" ).bind( "taphold", tapholdHandler );
```

to test the functionality, the tapholdHandler was just a simple alert.
but did not work.

also, i tried to use the

```
jQuery( "#1" ).on( "tap", function( event ) {alert('works!');} )
```

but without success.
however, i found out that it is possible to append this to the select element, but then it works for all the option elements within the select tag.
how can i trigger a longclick/taphold event on a single option element?
what i would like to do is to be able to longclick (hold the click) on a desired item and show a dialog which offers to delete the item from the list.

Answer (score 1):

your selector is wrong

`$('#1')` will select an element with id=1

change your code to

`$( "#1" ).bind( "taphold", tapholdHandler );`

You cannot bind events to `<option>` elements with any real precision. You can however as stated elsewhere bind to the `change` event of the select menu in this case

```
$('#select1').change(function(){
    var selected_option = $(this).find(':selected');
});
```

Comment: sorry, i misspelled the ids. i corrected them in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

[id-selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) sector is used like this

`$('#1')` will select an element with id=1

change your code to

```
$( "#1" ).bind( "taphold", tapholdHandler );
```

and

```
$( "#1" ).on( "tap", function( event ) {alert('works!');} )
```

Comment: sorry, i misspelled the ids. i corrected them in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

How about binding to 'change'? this will trigger whenever an element is selected or changed.

```
    $('#select1').change(function(){
         // action here
     });
```

Comment: but how would this detect the longclick?

Comment: If you are trying to detect a change in a <Select> i would reccomend detecting 'change' as this has broader support